# Alchemy4Tridion ResourceGroup.cs file has no AttachToView function anymore

Tags: web8, a4t

I'm creating a popup dialog inside plugin by Alchemy4Tridion, at WEB 8. The AttachToView function seems disappeared from the ResourceGroup.cs file. Any idea why?

```
using Alchemy4Tridion.Plugins.GUI.Configuration;
using Alchemy4Tridion.Plugins.GUI.Configuration.Elements;
namespace Tridion.Plugin.Publish.GUI
{
public class PublishPopupGroup : Alchemy4Tridion.Plugins.GUI.Configuration.ResourceGroup
{
    public PublishPopupGroup()
    {
        AddFile("Publish.js");
        AddWebApiProxy();
        AttachToView("PublishPopup.aspx");
        Dependencies.Add("Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME");
    }
}
}
```

The error is: the name AttachToView does not exist in the current context.

The Alchemy4Tridion.Plugin version is 1.0.0-beta6-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at the source code, it looks like the ResourceGroup class still has a public AttachToView function (see here : https://github.com/Alchemy4Tridion/Alchemy4Tridion/blob/master/Alchemy4Tridion.Plugins/GUI/Configuration/ResourceGroup.cs#L184)

Could you share the error that you get, or the relevant piece of source code so we have a better understanding of your problem ?

Based on your comment, you say you can't see version .08 in the package manager

This is what I see in my visual studio, when i search for alchemy in the nuget package manager
[image]

Comment: using Alchemy4Tridion.Plugins.GUI.Configuration;
using Alchemy4Tridion.Plugins.GUI.Configuration.Elements;

namespace Tridion.Plugin.Publish.GUI
{

    public class PublishPopupGroup : Alchemy4Tridion.Plugins.GUI.Configuration.ResourceGroup
    {
        public PublishPopupGroup()
        {
            AddFile("Publish.js");
            AddWebApiProxy();
            AttachToView("PublishPopup.aspx");
            Dependencies.Add("Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME");
        }
    }
}

Comment: The error is: the name AttachToView  does not exist in the current context

Comment: I have just tried to build a test plugin with the code you placed here, and it builds correctly (i don't get the error about not recognizing AttachToView)

I think the main problem is that you are using an old version of alchemy (the most recent version is 1.0.0-beta8-3

Comment: Inisde Nuget, the Alchemy4Tridion package only has version is 1.0.0-beta6-1. I need to manually build and reference version 1.0.0-beta8-3. After upgrade it, the AttachToView method is back.

Comment: When you look here, you can see the nuget version is available for version 8.3 as well : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Alchemy4Tridion.Plugin/

Comment: Yep, it is there. But for some reason we can only search beta6 out, unless we know the direct link for beta8. Any idea why?

Comment: qchen01, see my edited answer with a screenshot. It would be strange why you wouldn't be able to see beta 8, which version of visual studio are you using ?

Comment: I figure out why. I didn't check the box "include prerelease". After check it, everything is good now.  One more question: It seems version beta8 still refer Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client version 7.1, which doesn't contain some feature related to permission. How can we update this DLL version to 8?